# How to implement a derived class and call it from a Button?

Tags: c#

I am 57 years old. Other than using C# for analysing text data, my knowledge of C# is very limited. However, occasionally I try to learn some other aspects of C#. I also prefer to understand code created for windows applications rather than for console applications.

Could anyone please elaborate on the code given below which is taken from MSDN site with simple practical examples so that I can learn something from it. I think I need to create another class but how to implement it all and call it from a button in C#. Why do they say only derived classes can call 'AddGas'. Thanks in advance.

```
abstract class Motorcycle
{
    // Anyone can call this.
    public void StartEngine() {/* Method statements here */ }

   // Only derived classes can call this.
   protected void AddGas(int gallons) { /* Method statements here */ }

   // Derived classes can override the base class implementation.
   public virtual int Drive(int miles, int speed) { /* Method statements here */ return 1; }

   // Derived classes must implement this.
   public abstract double GetTopSpeed(); 
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let that you want to create a specific `Motorcycle` for instance a `Yamaha` that has another method that returns the color of the Motorcycle. Instead of creating all the method in `Motorcycle` from scratch for each motorcycle you want to create you could inherit from it as below:

```
public class Yamaha : Motorcycle
{       
    public string GetColor()
    {
        // ....
        return "Red";
    }

    // When a method in class is marked as abstract,
    // all the class that inherit should provide an implementation
    // of this method. Otherwise you would get a compilation error.
    public double GetTopSpeed()
    {
        return 200;
    }

    // When a method is marked as virtual, we have two options for the derived classes.
    // 1. Use the implementation provided int the base class.
    // 2. Override this implementation, define a method like below and provide
    // your implementation. 
    public override int Drive(int miles, int speed) 
    { 
        /* Method statements here */ return 2; 
    }

}
```

Furthermore, it's important to note here that you **can't** instantiate an abstract class (you can't create an object as `new Motorcycle()`).

> Why do they say only derived classes can call 'AddGas' ?

Because `AddGas` is marked as `protected`. Reading about access modifiers in C# would make this and other related things more clear.

Comment: I tried implementing your code with success. Because I have read  bits and pieces of theory, I could readily follow your suggestions.

Comment: I am glad that I helped :)

Answer (score 1):

Abstract classes are just templates or guides for how to make something.

In your example, it's a guide for how to make a Motorcycle. You can't actually *create* a Motorcycle. You can't go into a dealership and ask for one Motorcycle please.

A Honda? Kawasaki? 150cc? 650cc? What?

Your guide tells you that:

- It should be able to be started by someone (`*public* void StartEngine()`)
- Internally, should be able to add some petrol - sorry, British - (`*protected* void AddPetrol(int litres)`)
- It should be able to be driven by someone (`*public* virtual int Drive(int miles, int speed)`)
- It has a top speed that someone can read (`*public* abstract double GetTopSpeed()`)

From this, we can see that *anyone* can start it, drive it, and get it's top speed.

We can also see that the bike itself can add some petrol to itself (it's an *internal* combustion engine, after all).

You decide on a Honda. Why? Because that's the first Make that comes to mind. So you ask for that one over there. The salesman tells you ah, that's a good starter one, no frills, no extras, it just works. It's a

```
public class HondaBasic : Motorcycle {
    public override double GetTopSpeed()
    {
        return 60.0;
    {
}
```

It's cute! You should take it out for a spin...

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    // "Aww, it looks like something a child would ride!"
    var bike = new HondaBasic();
    bike.StartEngine();    

    // "Wow, is that in MPH or Km/h? Either way I could run faster than that!"
    var top = bike.GetTopSpeed();

    // "Well, lets take it for a spin, at least..."
    bike.StartEngine();
    var driven = bike.Drive(3, 30);
}
```

And so there you go, you took your Honda Basic out for a test drive, for 3 miles at 30 MPH.

I'm going to take liberties here and assume that Drive returns the time actually driven, because I figure time is what you get out when you give something a speed and distance.

Apparently you *planned* to go out for 3 miles at 30 MPH, and you apparently drove for... 1. Because that's what it said you did...

`public virtual int Drive(int miles, int speed) { return 1; }`

`driven` == 1 because the base class just returns 1 all the time! I doubt you managed 3 miles - at 30mph - in 1 minute?second? Not important.

I guess as there's nothing around to call AddGas, it probably ran out after only 1 minute?second?...

Well, that was awful. Why did they even make that model? Ok, what about that sweet thing in the corner? It's shiny! And looks as though it was actually build by people that knew... anything at all, to be honest.

```
public class KawasakiNinja : Motorcycle {
    private int _gas;

    public KawasakiNinja()
    {
        _gas = 100;
    }


    public override int Drive(int miles, int speed)
    {
        var timeWhateverValue = miles / speed;

        _gas -= timeWhateverValue;
        return timeWhateverValue;
    }

    public override double GetTopSpeed()
    {
        return 300;
    }

    protected override void AddGas(int gallons)
    {
        _gas += gallons;
    }

    public void FillErUp(int gallons)
    {
        AddGas(gallons);
    }
}
```

Well ok then... This bike looks to actually be something more than a disposable camera with wheels. It can actually be filled up!

Sounds good! Let's take her for a spin!

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    // "Mmm, shiny"
    var bike = new KawasakiNinja();

    // "Purrs like a kitten!"
    bike.StartEngine();

    // "How fast?!"
    var top = bike.GetTopSpeed();

    // "Sweet..."
    var driven = bike.Drive(1, 300);

    // "Holy cap it really can go 300! I bet it burns up fuel like there's no tomorrow, though! Let's pull over"
    bike.FillErUp(50);

    // "Enough to get back to the lot"
    driven = bike.Drive(1, 40);
}
```

Quite adventurous of you - burning away a single mile at 300 mph! According to Kawasaki's (our) maths, you drove that in 0 minutes?seconds?

Aaaand it had a way to fill the tank (and, frankly, this model actually *had* a tank).

So, there's something moderately basic for you.

The `abstract class` itself just describes how to do things. It may or may not include any actual functionality;

- It *did* specify the `Drive` method, and implemented it - albeit in a basic way
- It specified a `GetTopSpeed` method, but did *not* implement it (`abstract`). That method needs to be implemented in anything made from the abstract class - compiler complains at you if you miss that out, so it's easy enough to not miss

Anything derived from the abstract classes have access to everything the abstract class can do, and, if it's virtual, can override it's implementation. Alternatively, it may actually *need* to provide an implementation of some kind; where the abstract base knows that it will need to be able to something, but not exactly know what or how.

In the above example, it doesn't make sense that a non-existent bike would have a top speed at all - but we know that any real bike in general will have one - so any real bikes need to provide it.

Comment: I really liked your way oef explaining. Helped  me to grasp things better. As a person from foxpro, dbase background, I have real trouble understanding these things when I read theory. But you imaginatively lessened my pain and improved my understanding. @Krenom